# Multi Output Neural Network By Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have Input data include 48 or 52( this number is multiple of 4) and 3 outputs.        **For inputs are similar below:
1.34772 1.35783 1.35937 1.35158 1.33009
And Output -1,108,128**
First output always is -1 or 1 and second, third output integer between 80,140.
I like to train NN model that calculates all weights, biases,... according to this inputs and outputs.
[Sample Input and output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QfLU.png)
AX,AY and AZ are my outputs. Is that possible use Tensorflow for training such data in same time for 3 outputs?
Regards,

Comment: So u want the same model (i.e share weights) for all outputs? Moreover, what u mean by 48 or 52?

Comment: 48 inputs and 3 outputs

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that you can try is to output 3 values from the deep learning model. I have given below a sample code with the comments where necessary.

```
import tensorflow as tf

N_OUTPUTS = 3
N_INPUTS = 48
N_HIDDEN_UNITS =  # Define here
N_EPOCHS =  # define here

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_INPUTS], name='input')  # input here

outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_OUTPUTS], name='output')  # one sample is something like[Ax,Ay,Az]

# one hidden layer with 3 outputs
W = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_INPUTS, N_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_UNITS, N_OUTPUTS]))
}
biases = {
    'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_UNITS], mean=1.0)),
    'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_OUTPUTS]), mean=1.0)
}

hidden = tf.matmul(input, W['hidden']) + biases['hidden']  # hidden layer
output_ = tf.matmul(hidden, W['output']) + biases['output']  # outputs

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output_ - outputs))  # calculates the cost
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)  # optimazer

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):

    # _ = session.run([optimizer],feed_dict={input: , outputs : }) should feed input and output as [Ax,Ay,Az]
```

Above, I have created an NN model with just one hidden layer and then outputs 3 values (**[Ax, Ay, Az]**).

However, you can try something like above model if your **[Ax, Ay, Az]** are interdependent (*i.e* have a correlation). Otherwise, just build 3 independent models for the three outputs and train them separately.

Hope this helps.